# Can't import json spritesheet

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, pixi.js

I'm trying to make a game with PixiJS and I can't import spritesheet.
The error I'm getting is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scale' of undefined
```

For some reason this happens when I try to make an image in to a spritesheet. This error happens on the browser.
Spent few hours googling this, still couldn't make it work.

Webpack config. I read that json should be bundled correctly without any loaders:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Cool website',
        }),
      ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader',
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(glsl|vs|fs)$/,
                loader: 'shader-loader',
                options: {
                    glsl: {
                        chunkPath: path.resolve("/glsl/chunks")
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 9999
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
};
```

index.ts:

```
// all the setup

const loader = new Loader();

loader.add('hero', heroImage);

const sprites: { [name: string]: Sprite } = {};

loader.load((loader, resources) => {
    const sheet = new Spritesheet(resources.hero.texture.baseTexture, heroSprite); //error happens here

    const animatedSprite = new AnimatedSprite(sheet.animations['idle']);
    app.stage.addChild(animatedSprite);

    app.ticker.add(loop);
});
// loop function
```

Comment: What is `heroImage`? And `heroSprite`? You're using webpack so this sounds like a path issue. Did you check the console? The browser will try and load these images at some point.

Comment: heroImage is the path to the image and heroSprite is the object from json. I couldn't load json path (maybe because of typescript?) so i just found somewhere how to do the same just with an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.
Just used `copy-webpack-plugin` and copied all assets. Then just imported it like it's written in PixiJS documentation `loader.add('hero', '/assets/hero/hero.json');`